# Writing a R function with aggregation using data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I'm writing a R function with aggregations using data.table package. My table looks like:

```
Name1   Name2   Price
  A       F      6
  A       D      5
  A       E      2
  B       F      4
  B       D      7
  C       F      4
  C       E      2
```

My function looks like:

```
MyFun <- function(Master_Table, Desired_Column, Group_By){
  Master_Table <- as.data.table(Master_Table)
  Master_Table_New <-  Master_Table[, (Master_Table$Desired_Column), by=.(Desired_Column$Group_By)]
  return(Master_Table_New)
}
```

I want to calculate `df[, .(Group_Median = median(Price), by=.(Name1, Name2)]`
But when I apply it into my own function, it keeps giving me errors like: `

```
Error in `[.data.table`(Master_Table, , .(Med_Group = mean(Master_Table$Desired_Column)),  : 
  column or expression 1 of 'by' or 'keyby' is type NULL. Do not quote column names. Usage: DT[,sum(colC),by=list(colA,month(colB))] `
```

or:

```
Error in `[.data.table`(Master_Table, , .(Med_Group = mean(Master_Table$Desired_Column)),  : 
  column or expression 1 of 'by' or 'keyby' is type NULL. Do not quote column names. Usage: DT[,sum(colC),by=list(colA,month(colB))]
```

This would be the very first step of my whole work. If anyone knows anything about this, please let me know, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Why are you writing a function?

Comment: The function will contain more things, but the data.table part would be the base.

Comment: Why don't you group with `dplyr::group_by`, then use `mutate` to calculate Group_Median?

Comment: @M.zz.M I understood. You need to modify your function as mentioned in my answer so that it will work properly. I have given an example as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function should be written as:

```
MyFun <- function(Master_Table, Desired_Column, Group_By){
  Master_Table[, sapply(.SD, mean),  .SDcols = Desired_Column, by=Group_By]
}

#Have a close watch here how Group_By is prepared to provide multiple columns.
MyFun(DT, "Price", "Name1,Name2")
#     Name1 Name2 V1
# 1:     A     F  6
# 2:     A     D  5
# 3:     A     E  2
# 4:     B     F  4
# 5:     B     D  7
# 6:     C     F  4
# 7:     C     E  2
```

**Data**

```
DT <- read.table(text = 
"Name1   Name2   Price
A       F      6
A       D      5
A       E      2
B       F      4
B       D      7
C       F      4
C       E      2",
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

setDT(DT)
```

Comment: Hi MKR, really appreciate for your help! It is exactly what I want! But I still have a question -- why should I modify my function before using it?  Is it a special thing for data table when I want to insert it into a self-defined function?

Comment: @M.zz.M There are two ways. The function written by me expects a `data.table` type argument. Hence `setDT` call has been used to convert it to `data.table`. Another option is to call `setDT` within function itself. Since you had mentioned about `data.table` hence I kept my function expecting a `data.table`. Hope it clarifies your doubt.

Comment: @M.zz.M Also, as you can make out that there is no need of a function in your case. The one line which is part of my function can be used instead of function.

Comment: @M.zz.M Though you are relatively new user to SO hence wanted to inform about this link https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers . Probably you are aware about information on link.

Comment: Thank you for the advice and explanations! As a relatively new user, it definitely helps me a lot!  
Also, I rewrite the Group_By part in order to merge table. Following is my code: `MyFun <- function(Master_Table, Desired_Column, Group_By_A, Group_By_B)` and make `Group_By = c(Group_By_A, Group_By_B) ` I just wondering if you were me, would you have any more efficient solutions? Thank you.

Comment: There is a `with` argument in `data.table` which allows selecting columns using `"` e.i. "Plan" in `j` section. But that is not applicable for `by` section. Hence you have to follow the convention used by me in order to select multiple columns.

Comment: I'm so sorry for buzzing you again. Another thing I've been trying for a long time is: in the same function, I want to 1) create a subset where Desired_Column value ==  Mean(which is V1 in your answer). 2) I want to create a new column in the new table as Table$New = abs(Table$Mean  - 3) for example. They both work in regular R, but when I put it within my function, it doesn't work at all. I just wondering if there are any suggestions? I really appreciate your help and your time! Thank you!